# Schedule SQL Server query to execute and output a file

Tags: sql, sql-server, schedule

Alright guys, this should be a very simple request. I'd like to run a query (IE `Select * from tablex`) every night and have it automatically output to a text file on the same system.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at SSIS packages for Standard+ installations, or Windows Task Scheduler and SQLCMD for Express editions (or as alternative).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a new SQL Server Agent job, in the step put in your SELECT statement. In Advanced, tell it to output to a file. Done.

Comment: Thanks for answering this in the scope of the question, rather than recommending something else.

Answer (score 1):

Look at bcp.exe scheduled via Windows for possibly the simplest way...